# Why does drop down arrow in select change appearance and shift positon when I press refresh?

Tags: css

Why does the drop down arrow change appearance when I refresh the webpage? Thus moving the content for a second on both boxes. (select a category) (select a country)

Here's [the link](https://ziopee.com/)!

The drop down arrows in the 
(select a category) 
and 
(select a country) change while the page is refreshing.

```
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

select.small {
  padding: .9rem;
}

select.selectized {
  display: block !important;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.selectize-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.selectize-control .selectize-input {
  transition: .3s ease;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1.7rem;
  height: auto;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the selectize library is loaded asynchronously (e.g. it's not immediately applied).

So the first thing the browser does is parse the HTML, then load the CSS. At this point, the browser renders the web page. As your select components are `<select>` tags, the browser render them as is. At the same time it renders the initial page, the browser fetch the javascript files. Once it finishes loading them, it'll execute the scripts - and that's when selectize gets applied and replace the `select` dropdown with their custom JS implementation.

So how can we fix this? Well this depends a lot of the library you're using (and I'm not familiar with Selectize, so I'll only give you the concept - you'll need to figure out how to make this work with the library you're using)

The good thing about your current implementation is that it's "progressive enhancement". This mean the select can work fine if the JavaScript files do not load; or load slowly (for example on mobile device). To keep this feature the only thing you could do is to style the select with CSS to make them look as close to Selectize as possible. Right now you CSS rules are targetting `.selectize-control` and other library specific class name. You could try applying those classes directly in your HTML before Selectize loads; or style your select by not targeting the selectize classes.